# How to use get_option() without any filter?

Tags: customization, javascript, ajax, translation, options

I'm using the newest WordPress 3.3.1 and newest qTranslate 2.5.27. I have made some an AJAX script which returns a value and message in the current language.

Here I get my first problem, I solve it by sending in AJAX `lang` from `qtrans_getLanguage()` and using messages with `qtrans_use($lang, '<!--:pl-->PL message<!--:--><!--:de-->DE message<!--:-->');`

I have an wp_option in DB: `'example' = '<!--:pl-->polish text<!--:--><!--:de-->deutschland text<!--:-->'`
and when using `get_option('example')` I am always getting `Polish text`.

I was trying to `setlocale` in PHP but without any positive result.

`get_option()` is working correctly in any php WordPress file or template, but not in my AJAX...

EDIT:
In template:

```
$.post('<?php echo get_bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/sendmail.php', {
message: input_message,
lang: input_lang
}
```

In sendmail.php:

```
'destination_email' is set to '<!--:pl-->x@x.pl<!--:--><!--:de-->x@x.de<!--:-->'

$mail = _e(get_option('destination_email'));
```

Always getting Polish email... even

```
'setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE')'
```

Now I'm using hardcode email

```
$mail = qtrans_use($lang, '<!--:pl-->x@x.pl<!--:--><!--:de-->x@x.de<!--:-->');
```

...

Comment: Can you please post *actual code*, so we can better follow what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you are using [language tags](http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3&p=15#p15) around 'polish textdeutschland text' i.e. `<!--:pl-->polish text<!--:--><!--:de-->deutschland text<!--:-->` but that they got ignored when you posted your answer.

I'm pretty sure what you need to be doing is using the `__()` (which returns the translation for use in php code) and `_e()` (echo's direct to screen) wordpress functions. If you look at the qTranslate support forum [FAQ #14](http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3#p14), he uses the example:

```
<?php _e("<!--:en-->english text<!--:--><!--:de-->german text<!--:-->"); ?>
```

In your case I think you want to use:

```
<?php __(get_option('example')); ?>
```

This is assuming that you are using it within your plugin. If you're using it in a page template you'd use:

```
<?php _e(get_option('example')); ?>
```

Comment: I've edited my question. I'm not sure that you understand me. Thanks for the answer.